# Get server name from a client

Tags: emacsclient

I have a few Emacs servers running on my computer, and a few clients are attached to these servers. Is there a way to get which server a client is attached to from the window?

Comment: Please clarify how you arrange to have several Emacs servers running on your machine (are they running under different user-ids, or do you use something like `server-name`, ...?).  Please clarify also what you mean by "from the window".  E.g. show an example of the way you'd like to be able to distinguish them.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to emacs. I would like to run daemons by `emacs --daemon=NAME` with a few different `NAME`s and open a window by `emacsclient -c -s NAME`. The question is how to learn NAME from the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a pinch, `(emacs-pid)` will give you the server's process ID.

In *typical* cases, <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `server-name` is probably going to tell you what you need to know.

For example if you are simply using `emacs --daemon=NAME` and connecting with `emacsclient -s NAME`, then `server-name` will have the value `NAME`.

`(expand-file-name server-name server-socket-dir)` is more specific, if there's a chance of the socket directory varying.

If you're using TCP sockets instead of local sockets then things are a bit different again, with `server-auth-dir` being used.